# How to make a mat-select list have an option automatically selected

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

The list is binded to the .ts code:
Here is the html :

```
                        <mat-label>Тип на апликација:</mat-label>
                        <mat-select [(value)]="AppId" required #apptype="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="AppId" name="apptype" 
                            >
                            <mat-option>---</mat-option>
                            <mat-option  *ngFor="let applicationType of applicationTypes"  value="applicationType.ID" >
                                {{applicationType.Name}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                        <mat-error *ngIf="apptype && apptype.touched && apptype.errors && inputForm.submitted">
                            <span *ngIf="apptype.errors['required']">Ова поле е задолжително.</span>
                        </mat-error>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

How do i make one of the options automatically selected when i open the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make a direct edit to your code, but you didnt provide much, so here goes a very simple example:

This is your `ts` file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample {
  people: FormGroup;

  peopleArray=[{
    name:'name 1',
  },{
    name:'name 2',
  },{
    name:'name 3',
  }]

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit() {

        this.people = this.fb.group({
            people: [null, Validators.required]
        });

    const toSelect = this.peopleArray.find(p => p.name == "name 3");
    this.people.get('people').setValue(toSelect);
    }
}
```

This is your `html` file:

```
<form [formGroup]="people">
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
    <mat-select placeholder="person" formControlName="people">
        <mat-option>--</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let person of patientCategories" [value]="person">
            {{person.name}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>{{people.get('people').value | json}}</p>
</form>
```

As you can see, you just take the `people` object (`FormGroup instance`) and set its value to whatever you want. I couldn't make it more trivial then this.

Comment: You have no idea how profound the realization is that, instead of trying to force the option to highlight through calling whatever selection functions there are on the component, it will do it all for you automatically if you just use the binding that you already had set up for exactly that purpose.